Como puedo organizar este algoritmo de excel?
Sub CalcularNota()
    Dim nota1 As Double, nota2 As Double, nota3 As Double, nota4 As Double
    Dim notaDefinitiva As Double
    Dim calificacion As String
    
    ' Solicitar al usuario que ingrese las 4 notas
    nota1 = InputBox("Ingrese la primera nota:")
    nota2 = InputBox("Ingrese la segunda nota:")
    nota3 = InputBox("Ingrese la tercera nota:")
    nota4 = InputBox("Ingrese la cuarta nota:")
    
    ' Calcular la nota definitiva
    notaDefinitiva = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4) / 4
    
    ' Determinar la calificación cualitativa
    Select Case notaDefinitiva
        Case Is >= 4.5
            calificacion = "E"
        Case Is >= 5#, 4.5
            calificacion = "S"
        Case Is >= 4#, 4.4
            calificacion = "B"
        Case Is >= 3.9, 3.5
            calificacion = "A"
        Case Is >= 3.4, 3#
            calificacion = "D"
        Case Is >= 2.9, 2#
            calificacion = "I"
          Case Is >= 1#
    Case Else
    End Select
    
    ' Mostrar la nota definitiva y la calificación cualitativa
    MsgBox "La nota definitiva es: " & notaDefinitiva & vbCrLf & _
           "La calificación cualitativa es: " & calificacion
End Sub

El código muestra perfectamente la nota, pero a la hora de mostrar la letra asignada se equivoca, y solo pone "E"
El ejercicios que me pusieron es este: Elabore un algoritmo que le permita al profesor ingresar las 4 notas que obtuvo un alumno y el computador le muestre la nota definitiva y la calificación cualitativa que es:
“E” si es mayor o igual a 4.5
“S” si es mayor o igual a 4.0 y menor de 4.5
“B” si es mayor o igual a 3.5 y menor de 4.0
“A” si es mayor o igual a 3.0 y menor de 3.5
“D” si es mayor o igual a 2.0 y menor de 3.0
“I” si es menor de 2.0

Solo que no entiendo tanto excel y por eso no se como organizar esa parte

Tus rangos estan incorrectos de acuardo al problema

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Excel es una planilla de calculos... lo que no entendes es vba, que es distinto... ahora no se que quisiste hacer con 5#, pero basicamente como te dicen arriba, tu unico problema es que escribiste mal los rangos... nada mas que eso...

Sí, sé que esta mal. Pero entonces como puedo escribir los rangos correctamente?

siempre mayor.. lo dice el ejercicio Case Is >= 4.5
calificacion = "E"
Case Is >= 4 calificacion = "S" etc etc... no tenes que hacer mas que eso.. cae por el que corresponde y se va...

ahora, me gustaria saber de donde sacaste el 5# y todos esos.. para poder explicarte que esta mal.. si no, fue solo falta de leer la documentacion de como se escribe un case...

En las instrucciones Select Case para definir un intervalo numérico se utiliza to. Por ejemplo:
Case 4 to 4.5 incluye cualquier valor entre 4 y 4.5, ambos inclusive.
Por otro lado, el orden de los casos influye en el resultado. Por ejemplo.
Select Case notadefinitiva
  Case is >= 4.5
    calificacion="E"
  Case 4 to 4.5
    calificación = "S"
...

Aquí el código primero ejecutará Case is=> 4.5. Si notadefinitiva es mayor o igual a 4.5 devolverá E pero si no, irá al siguiente caso, que es 4 to 4.5. Es cierto que 4.5 está incluido en el intervalo, pero si el código llega aquí sabemos seguro que 4.5 no es porque si no hubiera ejecutado el paso anterior.
Pues así con todo. Te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial:

Select
Case

